# What are the biggest risks when switching to UTF-8?

Tags: sql-server, database, encoding

Our team is planning on updating the collation encodings on our SQL Server database to UTF-8.  We are also planning on updating our table schemas to use `nvarchar()` for true Unicode character support. What we are trying to identify however, is what are the potential land mines we're going to encounter by doing so?

For example, are our queries going to run slower? is there a chance that current data in the database could be corrupted?

For reference, SQL Server is being used as a back end to a PHP web application that runs on Apache on a Linux host.

Comment: what was the original collation? if switching from ASCII there shouldn't really be any concerns other than an increase in space

Comment: And if using 2008 R2 and above, with data compression, space won't really be an issue until you start actually storing characters that require 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [MSDN SQL Server Books Online on NVARCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) - SQL Server only supports UCS-2 (2 byte per character = UTF-16), but this is **true Unicode** as you say.

Also see [this question (and its answer) on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/sql-server-2005-2008-utf-8-collation-charset) for a more thorough explanation and background.

The major **drawback** of using all `nvarchar` columns is the fact that this just plain uses twice the storage space compared to `varchar` - all characters are stored as 2 bytes. Other than that - I don't see any big issues with using `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`...